# Packaging a Python Program with custom built libraries

Tags: python, distutils

I am trying to find a solution for a problem I am working on.  I have a python program which is is using a custom built sqlite3 install (which allows > 10 simultaneous connections) and in addition requires the use of Tix (which does not come as a stand install with the python package for the group I am distributing to.)

I want to know if there is a way to specify to distutils to use this certain sqlite3 build and include this third party install of Tix, such that I can distribute the file as an rpm and not require the end user to install Tix or modify their sqlite3 install...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution: Create a custom package for that program containing the custom sqlite3/etc. stuff and use relative imports to refer to those custom subpackages from a main module in your package, which you'd hook into with a simple importing script that would execute a `your_package.run()` function or something. You'd then use distutils to install your package in site-packages or whatever.